# Pygame freezing window when trying to move object

Tags: python, pygame

im trying to make a program in pygame that can make a object slow down/speed up in a certain amount of time. heres the code:

```py
import pygame,time,random

class GameObject(pygame.sprite.Sprite):
    all_objects = pygame.sprite.Group()
    def __init__(self, x, y, obj_type):
        super().__init__()
        self.image = pygame.Surface((20, 20))
        self.image.fill((255, 0, 0))
        self.rect = self.image.get_rect()
        self.rect.center = [x, y]
        self.obj_type = obj_type  
        self.speedfactor = None
        GameObject.all_objects.add(self)
    def move(self):
        if self.obj_type == "P":
            keys = pygame.key.get_pressed()
            if keys[pygame.K_w]:
                self.rect.y -= 1
            if keys[pygame.K_a]:
                self.rect.x -= 1
            if keys[pygame.K_s]:
                self.rect.y += 1
            if keys[pygame.K_d]:
                self.rect.x += 1
        if self.obj_type == "J":
            keys = pygame.key.get_pressed()
            if keys[pygame.K_j]:
                self.a('r',2,1)
    def getKicked(self):
        if self.obj_type == "O":
            print("kick")
    def a(self,direction,speedfactor,timefactor,sp=False): #if sp true it gets faster if false it slow down
        direction = direction
        speedslow = sp
        self.speedfactor = float(speedfactor)
        timefactor = float(timefactor)
        mpfactor = float(0.2)
        while speedfactor > 0:
            if direction == 'r':
                self.rect.x = max(0, min(self.rect.x + self.speedfactor, 800 - self.rect.width))
            if direction == 'u':
                self.rect.y = max(0, min(self.rect.y + self.speedfactor, 600 - self.rect.height))
            if direction == 'l':
                self.rect.x = max(0, min(self.rect.x - self.speedfactor, 800 - self.rect.width))
            if direction == 'd':
                self.rect.y = max(0, min(self.rect.y - self.speedfactor, 600 - self.rect.height))
            if speedslow == True:
                self.speedfactor += mpfactor
            elif speedslow == False:
                self.speedfactor -= mpfactor
    def update(self):
        collisions = pygame.sprite.spritecollide(self, GameObject.all_objects, False)
        for obj in collisions:
            if obj != self and self.obj_type != obj.obj_type:
                print("Collision detected with {obj.obj_type} object")
            if self.obj_type == "O" and obj.obj_type == "P":
                self.getKicked()
    def checkkeystroke(self):
        keys = pygame.key.get_pressed()
        if keys[pygame.K_j] and self.obj_type == "J":
            self.a('r',2,0.1,False)

pygame.init()
screen = pygame.display.set_mode((800, 600))
pygame.display.set_caption("COLLISION TEST")
screenrect = screen.get_rect()

'''obj1 = GameObject(200, 300, "P")
obj2 = GameObject(400, 300, "O")
obj3 = GameObject(500, 300, "C")'''

obj4 = GameObject(200,100, "J")

clock = pygame.time.Clock()

running = True
while running:
    clock.tick(30)
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            running = False
    for obj in GameObject.all_objects:
        obj.move()
        obj.update()
        obj.checkkeystroke()
    screen.fill((0, 0, 0))
    for obj in GameObject.all_objects:
        screen.blit(obj.image, obj.rect)
    pygame.display.flip()

pygame.quit()
```

i expected if i pressed the "j" key on my keyboard the gameobject will move and either slow down/speed up. what actually happened is that the program window freezes (not responding) and i have to close the idle window.

Answer (score 1):

`while speedfactor > 0:` is an infinite loop, because `speedfactor` is not changed in the loop. Likely you meant `self.speedfactor > 0:`. Note that the method is called in the applicaition loop, so you probably don't want a loop in the loop. Replace `while speedfactor > 0:` with `if self.speedfactor > 0:`.